Movie with multiple love interests trying to work out who to marry
A guy wants to have everything though he doesn't need it (there's a scene where he holds up the board to buy something at auction and there's a man who doesn't want him buy because it's not necessary). He meet a girl in a shop and both try to buy a wood cabinets(?). Then there's another guy and girl and these guys both love a girl more than another girl. They decide to get married so they call a woman to organize two weddings and to decide for them who will marry who.
The woman switches the two girl and tell the person who came to the girl's house first that he will marry that girl. Two guys run to a girl then discover that it's not her, so they run to another house. This girl chases them and pretends to fall down, so a guy in a car leans out to sure that she's OK. This guy come to the another bride first so they go to the wedding to marry. But when they just about marry, this groom find out that he love the one who pretends fall down so he come back to that bride, in the end this couple get married. (The main casts all have black hair, and i thinks it maybe an asian movie (korean, japan, china or thailand)). I saw this movie maybe in 2010 on the TV.

Country\language? Approximate year of release?

If you're using the same account, you should be able to comment on your question rather than answering it. Please don't "answer" your question in response to comments. Also, if you know that you saw it a "long time ago", even telling us about when you saw it would help. Was it 10 years ago, or 20? That restricts what films it could possibly be.

Sounds like the Hong Kong screwball comedy The Shopaholics from 2006.

Compulsive disorders plague Hong Kong: Fong Fong Fong, a foundling who's now a nurse, is a shopaholic who seeks psychiatric help from Kan Yan (Choosey) Lee, who's frozen by an inability to choose. Into the mix come Kung Fu (Richie) Ho, a wealthy man who is stingy but also will buy anything someone else wants, and Ding Dong Ding, Lee's binge-eating bargain-shopping ex-girlfriend who reappears in hopes Lee will now choose her. Both men propose to both women who say yes to both. Family and friends are inept at helping to sort it out, and even if the four get the wedding vows straight, will anyone be cured? Does Hong Kong need more than a Prozac?

Pretty sure that the woman you mentioned is a psychiatrist that tries to pair these 2 couples properly by messing around with them, leading to chaos. Here's the trailer:



